# Laravel 5.4 : Move files to other dedicated server once upload completed

Tags: php, laravel, ssh

I'm beginner in Laravel, using latest version of laravel (5.4). Trying to upload a file to server using file upload form and that should move to another server automatically once upload has completed.  Is there any built in functions available in laravel or any other possible methods to achieve this?

Comment: What you mean with "another server"? Laravel ships with support to upload to AWS S3 and others cloud storages services.

Comment: there are a lot of options available , please provide some code or an issue . This question is very broad https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#storing-uploaded-files

Comment: @felipsmartins  Trying to move the files to another dedicated server with encryption.

Comment: Why not have the upload script directly onto the other server that makes more sense than moving it between servers?

Comment: @PetarVasilev I agree with you, but this is for an admin dashboard where a lot of db operations perform along with it, So it is bit hard to host the upload script in the other server

Comment: Then you should consider Avik's answer or better yet use one of the cloud providers like Amazon's S3

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel's native FTP driver, by adding this into your **config/filesystems.php**

```
'ftp' => [
    'driver'   => 'ftp',
    'host'     => 'ftp.example.com',
    'username' => 'your-username',
    'password' => 'your-password',

    // Optional FTP Settings...
    // 'port'     => 21,
    // 'root'     => '',
    // 'passive'  => true,
    // 'ssl'      => true,
    // 'timeout'  => 30,
],
```